# Springs: creating a Restful service without annotating the domain classes with @xml tags

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, marshalling, castor

I need to create a restful service. I have no access to some classes but need to send the same classes in the result. Is there a way to map the object to xml. I tried using org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller  but it gives response with extra tags in the xml like

```
<bean-property-binding-result field-error-count="0" global-error-count="0" error-count="0">
```

Is there a way to get it done using castor marshaller? If not can anyone redirect to write page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using velocity templates as xml templates and returning that xml as response for the call.